# Passing $routeProvider path to another function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very new to Angularjs.

What I need to do is pass the path that the `$routeProvider` is using for the view to an additional javascript function `currentPath()`. Below is the test code for the `routeProvider` but not sure how I would pass the path to function `currentPath()` which is in another framework:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {      
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'Partials/View1.html'
            })
        .when('/view2',
            {
                controller: 'SimpleController',
                templateUrl: 'Partials/View2.html'
            })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

where do you need the path? AngularJS is build around (mostly) the idea of Dependency injection (DI).

So, if you need the path that is currently active within the controller function that is being executed for that route, have a look at `$location`:

```
function SimpleController($scope, $location) {
  console.log($location.path()); //the current path

  //assign the path to the scope
  $scope.path = $location.path();
}
```

What happens here is that you inject `$location`, when you need it. By attributing it to the `$scope` you can access it in the partial currently in use. For further info, have a look at the docs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location).

EDIT:

Suppose you have an outer function that is available to the controller, maybe part of an object (i.e. a Framework), let's call it `A`:

```
var A;
A = {
  currentPath: function(path) {
    //do something with the path
  }
}

//as long as a is available in the scope surrodung your controller, this should work
function SimpleController($scope, $location) {
  $scope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    //this will be triggered after a location has changed,
    //other event to be tried out can be:
    // * $routeChangeStart
    // * $routeChangeSuccess
    // * $locationChangeStart
    A.currentPath($location.path());
  });

  //call it once initially
  A.currentPath($location.path());
}
```

Comment: Can the path be passed to a js function directly? Just to clarify, I'm passing it to a separate framework.

Comment: Well, that depends if that function is available to the controller (the controller is, after all just a function and can access the variables of the outer scope), could you give a fiddle or an example?

Comment: I have another framework with an object that has a function aa.currentpath(currPath). I'm not sure how I would access the $location.path() in my function. I need aa.currentpath(currPath) to be aware anytime a new view is loaded.